# Creating banner with pure CSS: z-index on pseudo-element not working as expected

Tags: css, css-position, pseudo-element

The code below should produce a simple ribbon, 3D-effect is achieved by CSS pseudo-elements. But for some reason, the visual effect isn't working correctly because the left and right "wings" of the ribbon shoud appear behind the front part, but actually they appear in front of it. Somehow, the z-indexes (+1, -1) are not working as expected. Checked out [z-index not working on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090390/z-index-not-working-on-pseudo-element) but couldn't trace down the issue.

```css
/* Color definitions */
:root {
  --color-orange: hsla(26, 83%, 50%, 1);
  --color-orange-darkened: hsl(26, 71%, 44%);
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
}


.shc-ribbon {
  z-index: 1;
}

.shc-ribbon span {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.shc-ribbon span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: var(--color-orange);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shc-ribbon span::before,
.shc-ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -10px;
  border: 20px solid var(--color-orange-darkened);
  z-index: -1;
}

.shc-ribbon span::before {
  left: -30px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.shc-ribbon span::after {
  right: -30px;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.shc-ribbon span h3::before,
.shc-ribbon span h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  top: -10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #272727 transparent;
}

.shc-ribbon span h3::before {
  left: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.shc-ribbon span h3::after {
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shc-ribbon">
  <span>
    <h3>WELCOME</h3>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `h3` in `span` is invalid HTML to begin with …

Comment: Apply the background color to `h3` instead of `span` (after you replaced the latter by a proper `div` or something, so that this nesting is allowed), and you should be there alrerady.

Comment: indeed, markup isn't valid. but it's generated by a CMS and unfortunately I have to use the markup the way it is …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html code to code below:

```
<div class="shc-ribbon"> 
    <span>
        <h3 style="background-color: hsla(26, 83%, 50%, 1)">WELCOME</h3> 
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't a z-index issue so far …